# How to learn website development

Tags: web-development

I want to learn how to make websites, but I don't know how to go about it.
I did learn some HTML, and right now learning CSS from www.w3schools.com.

Can anyone tell me what I should learn next and what other things I need to learn to start making websites? Also refer to the study material if you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to start from in web development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543091/where-to-start-from-in-web-development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have learned HTML and CSS, then you have two main routes open to you from there: the natural split in web development between front-end and back-end. For example, if you like design then I'd suggest JavaScript and a graphic package like Photoshop. The back-end would be to look at a language like Ruby, Python, Perl, PHP, or C# with SQL for databases.

You'll need to know a little bit of everything in the end, so have a go with everything just so you're aware of it all, and then you can end up where you're most comfortable (and forge helpful working relationships with those who like bits you don't :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP or Javascript (or both) could be a good direction to go next, either will provide a lot of powerful options for your web projects.  www.w3schools.com has a lot of info/reference for either...

PHP: [www.php.net](http://www.php.net)

Javascript: good place to find tons of info on Javascript is here  at [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)